# Alert Dialog code not being executed in if else statement android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-button

I have a button where if the user presses the button it will send an sms message to the selected phone number which works fine. The problem is when the user hasn't selected a phone number, the app is not executing my Alert dialog code where it will display a message box saying "No Modem Selected" and just jumping to the code in the else statement where it tries to send a message to a number that doesn't exist.

```
btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // Build an Alert Dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());

        // Set a title for alert dialog
        builder.setTitle("Start Engine?");

        // Ask the final question
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure want to start the Engine?");

        // Set the alert dialog yes button click listener
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                if(SelectedPhNo == null)
                {
                    // This code below is not being executed 
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Modem Error");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("No Modem Selected");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Start Engine
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), CommandsFragment.class);
                    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 0, intent, 0);

                    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
                    sms.sendTextMessage(SelectedPhNo, null, start, pi, null);

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Start Engine Command Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    inboxArrayAdapter.insert("Command: " + start + "\n" + strDate, 0);

                }
            }
        });

        // Set the alert dialog no button click listener
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                // Do something when No button clicked
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Command Aborted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        // Display the alert dialog on interface
        dialog.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Most likely your variable SelectedPhNo is not actually null.  It may be empty "", or it may have spaces in it.  You need to set a breakpoint on the if(SelectedPhNo line and then display the value of SelectedPhNo to see if it is actually null or something else.  If something else that is invalid, you will need to add that to the 'if' statement (null or "" or length <= 0...)

Comment: I went through the debugger and it turns out since I was using SharedPreferences, it was defaulting to the default value ,hence the SelectedPhNo variable was never null